# Deploying Python Flask on Azure Get error 500

Tags: python, azure, flask, deployment

In the following hour's i tried to deploy Python with flask on Microsoft azure platform.

I used New app "flask", assign with their server. deployed by git. 
after deployment finished (its showed Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)
Then I set up on options that i am using python 3.4 version and it fixed it up.

After Deployment succeeds I tried to see the site and I got :
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

I am a beginner in deploying and I search up all over. I really wish somebody could help me find the right answer.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Woule you please post more details of Internal Server Error ExceptionTrace log to let me help you? You could find logs in Kudu.

Comment: This is the python Logs :
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat). Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27
(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record d:\local\temp\pip-pychep-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\include\site\python2.7 failed with error code 1 in D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\lxml

I fixed it up by using the Python 3.4 on settings, maybe I shouldn't go with that?

Comment: running build_ext

building 'lxml.etree' extension

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat). Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27

This is the error from the deploy

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research on this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/11/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/) which mentioned content below about your issue:

> When you see "unable to find vcvarsall.bat", it means you're
>   installing a package that has an extension module, but only the source
>   code. "vcvarsall.bat" is part of the compiler in Visual Studio that is
>   necessary to compile the module.

I think your issue occurred because that during the flask project deployed to azure, pip has problems installing the `lxml` library.As mentioned in this [document](http://lxml.de/), `lxml` library is written in **C** which requires a **compiler** before it's installation.

Unfortunately,a compiler is not available on the machine running the web app in Azure App Service. So, you need to do this compilation locally.
You can follow the steps as below:

***Step 1***:Use `pip wheel` command line to generate `.whl` file of `lxml` package.In addition,you can directly download generated `.whl` file [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml).

[image]

***Step2***：Create the wheelhouse folder under the requments.txt file's sibling directory and put the `.whl` file in wheelhouse folder.

***Step3***: Edit your requirements.txt to add the `--find-links` option at the top.

```
--find-links wheelhouse
lxml==3.8.0
```

***Step4***：Deploy your flask project to azure.

For more details , please refer to the **Troubleshooting - Package Installation** chapter in the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-create-deploy-flask-app) and [wheel document](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Hope it helps you.